# Crear Procesos almacenados en MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

vengo con mi siguiente pregunta, es posible crear procesos almacenados en MongoDb o alguna alternativa  para agilizar una consulta con gran cantidad de datos en una base de datos de Mongodb?

Comment: tus consultas se ponen muy lentas?

Comment: demaciado, hablamos de una base de datos de minimo 27000 elementos.

Comment: por lo general mongo es muy ágil en tema de consultas te recomiendo que mires el log que genera mongo hay puedes ver donde es que el se queda o la otra seria es que el servidor no tiene los recursos suficientes (procesador o ram )para traer la consulta en el tiempo  estimado .

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Fatima eso es una base chiquita para cualquier tipo de base de datos. por favor agrega mas informacion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MongoDB** no tiene procedimientos almacenados, aunque tiene una función parecida: podemos almacenar funciones dentro de la base de datos. Un ejemplo:

```
db.system.js.save(
{
   _id:"findLast10",
   value: function(){
        return db.people.find
        (
          {},
          {name:1}
        ).sort({name:-1}).limit(10).pretty().toArray();
 }
});
```

Si ejecutas el código anterior en la consola, estará guardando una función **JavaScript** en la base de datos, **find** en realidad devuelve un cursor, se tiene que añadir el **toArray** para devolver los resultados, en lugar de el propio cursor.

Puedes revisar [Aquí](http://charlascylon.com/2014-02-06-mongodb-trucos-y-consejos-opciones-de-la-consola) algunos trucos para MongoBB